# Cannot make AMD Radeon RX550 work on Debian 9.4

Tags: debian, drivers, gpu, radeon

I followed [this](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Installation) manual in hope that after reboot cinnamon's software rendering mode would stop to annoying at my screen. But not helped.

I did:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
$ sudo apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-ati
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version (13.0.6-1+b2).
xserver-xorg-video-ati is already the newest version (1:7.8.0-1+b1).
firmware-linux-nonfree is already the newest version (20161130-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 0
```

After reboot nothing changed. I have low resolution and software redering mode on.

**UPD**

`xserver-xorg-video-radeon` is also already installed

**UPD 2**

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1465.908] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  1465.908] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[  1465.908] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  1465.910] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

`xserver-xorg-video-radeon` is also already installed

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the kernel, firmware-amd-graphics and mesa from backports. See https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2018/11/01/getting-radeon-rx-550-to-work-under-debian-stretch/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the radeon driver for a radeon.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

And then of course there used to be the proprietary drivers, fglrx, but I'm not sure they're kept up to date.  Tried last weekend and they seemed to be seriously outdated.

Comment: This package is also already installed. No effect

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed it in your question.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Any errors in /var/log/Xorg.0.log.  Lines marked "(EE)".  What processor does your notebook have?

Comment: updated question with errors of file that you requested

Comment: I had a look at the manual you followed, and learned this: "Support for newer AMD graphics hardware is provided by the xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu package. ".   I'll give it a try myself this evening.

Comment: Please check if your kernel driver has been loaded.  Or what driver has been loaded.   "lsmod | grep amdgpu".   Is "Debian 9.4" recent?  (I've switched to Devuan).

Comment: `lsmod | grep amdgpu` gave no output. Yep, 9.4 is the latest stable release of Debian

Comment: Check if you find amdgpu.ko in /lib/modules.  If so, has another driver been loaded that prevents amdgpu from loading?

Comment: No, only `4.9.0-6-amd64` folder is inside `/lib/modules`

Comment: You will have to search:  " find /lib/modules -name 'amdgpu.ko' ".

Comment: Yes, here is a file `/lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu.ko
`

Comment: And previously I've only installed packages that are pointed in the question

Comment: I'm wondering what driver would be loaded now.  As root, run " dmesg | grep 'dr[im]' ", perhaps that will tell us.